# Magento2.3 : Email template address variable not displays the value

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, variables

The email template doesn't get a shipping method variable.

[image: Email template]

As you can see `$billing.getName` not works.
Shipping and Billing information is empty.
Maybe something wrong with forms or submitting process?

Comment: This email template is magento 1 to magento 2 in migrate.
Please check all email template also.

Comment: @Vijay-CyberLocker how can I back default email templates?

Comment: You can select default email template or create new email template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For email template changes following section

```
    For Guest User

    {{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}

    For Customer

    {{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}

    Billing Information:

    {{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}

    Payment Method:

    {{var payment_html|raw}}

    Shipping Information:

    {{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}

    Shipping Method:

    {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the customer name in Email template, Please Use

> {{trans "%name," name=$billing.getName()}}

For billing and shipping address, Please use below code respectively.

> #### {{trans "Billing Info"}}
>
> {{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}
>
> #### {{trans "Shipping Info"}}
>
> {{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}

Answer (score 1):

For guest email

```
<p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>
```